# Access Element using D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have the following element on the page:

```
<div id="chart_title">
</div>
```

If I want to change the text using D3, I know I can use:
d3.select("#chart_title").html("title");

Is there a way I can use the D3 selector, but then just get access to the div itself?  I tried:

```
d3.select("#chart_title")[0]
```

but I just end up seeing the div in the console without any of the properties I want to look at.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the attributes of the element in the same way as for any other elements, e.g.

```
d3.select("#chart_title").attr("id", "new_name");
```

You can also set style attributes etc this way.